# FB.getLoginStatus showing I'm connected after deleting permissions?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**An abridged version of my code:**

```
$('#de-auth_button').click(function(){
  FB.api('/me/permissions', 'delete', function (response) {
    console.log(response); // true
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      console.log(response.status); // connected
    });
  });
});
```

The comments represent the result of clicking this button while logged in and with permissions to the app (`connected`).

Clicking the button a 2nd time gives an error message (access token needed) for the first `console.log` and a response of `not_authorized` for the 2nd (which is what I'm trying to accomplish after one click)

Comment: The result of getting the login status is cached – if you want it “real time”, you’ll have to use the `force` parameter when calling the method, see docs.

Comment: Ahh, I somehow missed that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: @CBroe if you want to put that as an answer, I'd be happy to give you a check mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of getting the login status is cached – if you want it “real time”, you’ll have to use the `force` parameter when calling the `FB.getLoginStatus` method, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/